# Convert Twilio Date Time Format into mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js, datetime, twilio, sequelize.js

I have this date-time format coming from Twilio.

`2019-03-28T11:09:49.000Z`

I want to convert this into this and insert into MySQL.

`2019-05-07 07:53:50`

I have tried using `DATE_FORMAT()` but didn't get success.

Edit: This is what I have tried.

```
UPDATE table_name 
date = DATE_FORMAT('2019-03-28T11:09:49.000Z', '%m/%d/%Y %H:%i:%s %c/%e/%Y %T')
WHERE id = id;
```

Comment: Can you share the code which tries to insert the data in mysql? And also explain what issue you are facing?

Comment: Just made an edit to the question @ChetanRanpariya

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert the date you get to a unix timestamp using JavaScript/Node.js, then insert it into the database like so:

```
const date = new Date('2019-03-28T11:09:49.000Z');
const timestamp = date.getTime()

UPDATE table_name date = FROM_UNIXTIME(?) WHERE id = id;
```

Comment: you might lose the timezone information. depends if you are using `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP` as the field type.